# Por que não consigo obter valor retornado por função?

Tags: javascript

Não consigo obter o valor retornado da função, qual seria o motivo? Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Em minha [página HTML](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/cursos.html) tenho a seguinte função:

```
function montarCursos(){
            var cursos = controller.getCursos();

            if(cursos != null){
                for(var i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++){
                    $("#cursos").append('<button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" data-transition ="slide" onclick="controller.setNomeCurso("' + cursos[i].Value +'")">' + cursos[i].Name + '</button>')
                }
            }   
        }
```

[Controller.js](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/controllers/cursosController.js)

```
var controller = {
getCursos: function () {

        function carregarCursos() {
            var resultado = [];
            var cursos = new cursosDao();
            resultado = cursos.getCursos();
            if (resultado.length > 0) {
                return resultado;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        loadDependence("Dao/cursosDao.js", carregarCursos);
    }
}
```

[loadDependence.js](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/controllers/loadDependence.js):

```
function loadDependence(url, callback) {

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

[cursosDao.js](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/Dao/cursosDao.js)

```
function cursosDao() {
    this.getCursos = function() {
        var cursos = [];
        cursos.push({
            "Value" : "Anáse de Sistemas",
            "Name" : "Anáse de Sistemas"
        });

        cursos.push({
            "Value" : "Ciência da Computação",
            "Name" : "Ciência da Computação"
        });

        return cursos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria melhor você colocar o código aqui no lugar de um link para um site externo.

Comment: Pergunta editada, me desculpem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o `return` dentro da funcão  `carregarCursos` só se aplica ao `carregarCursos`. Ele não vai "pular pra fora" e servir para retornar um valor pro `getCursos`. Na forma que seu código está escrito, `getCursos` vai sempre retornar `undefined`, sem esperar que os cursos sejam carregados.

Uma maneira de verificar isso é botar um console.log no final:

```
getCursos: function () {
    /*...*/
    loadDependence("Dao/cursosDao.js", carregarCursos);
    console.log("Nao está esperando pelo loadDependence...");
    return 17; // E está chegando no final da função 
}
```

Infelizmente, não tem uma meneira bonita de resolver esse problema em Javascript. Você vai ter que fazer  o `getCursos` usar uma API com callbacks ao invés de retornar a lista de cursos.

```
getCursos: function (onDone) {
    loadDependence("Dao/cursosDao.js", function() {
        var resultado = [];
        var cursos = new cursosDao();
        cursos.getCursos(function(resultado){
            if (resultado.length > 0) {
                onDone(resultado);
            } else {
                onDone(null);
            }
        });
    });
}

controller.getCursos(function(cursos){
  if(cursos != null){
    for(var i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++){
      /*...*/
    }
  }
}
```

Nesse exemplo também assumi que o `cursos.getCursos` pode ter que fazer uma requisição assíncrona e portanto também precisaria retornar o valor via callback. Se não precisar fazer request pode continuar usando a interface síncrona que você já estava usando.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta, mas mesmo depois da alteração infelizmente ainda não consigo obter o valor retornado. Existe alguma outra alternativa para fazer tudo isso? Eu gostaria de deixar bem estruturado o projeto para eventuais manutenções.

Comment: Converter o código pra usar continuações ao invés de retornos é algo que vai dar trabalho e é uma das maiores chatices de trabalhar com Javascript.  E o resultado fica feio mesmo. (Dê uma pesquisada por *promises* e por *generators* se você quiser domar as callbacks)

Comment: Obrigado mesmo assim, vou aceitar sua resposta. Eu estava lutando pra não colocar as tags script na página HTML manualmente, estava deixando dinâmico. Mas acho melhor eu simplificar meu trabalho.

Comment: Se o problema são só os módulos carregados na página, tem umas ferramentas como o [browserify](http://browserify.org/) que permitem que você requisite os módulos no seu Javascript sem ter que adicionar um monte de tags no html. Basicamente, ele pega todos os arquivos que precisar e concatena num "arquivão" só.